# Magento 2: Get order ID and Date in DHL Shipping Carrier model

Tags: magento2, orders, model, dhl

I have a requirement to attach the order ID and order date to the xml request (ShipmentRequest) located in /magento/dhl/model/Carrier.php

Is there a way to retrieve the order ID linked to this shipping request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out using:

```
$orderNumber = $rawRequest->getOrderShipment()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
$orderDate = $rawRequest->getOrderShipment()->getOrder()->getCreatedAt();
```